# ASP.NET MVC transfer data from controller to view with viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In my controller I have

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //...
    //...
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel()
    {
        MTohum = mTohum,
        STohum = sTohum,
        BTohum = bTohum,
        TKota = tKota,
        KKota = kKota,
        BKota = bKota,
    };
    //return Content("tkota : " + tKota.ToString() + " kkota : " + kKota.ToString() + " bkota : " + bKota.ToString());
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

When I remove comment and return Content() I can see that values are not null.

On the view side:

```
//..html codes..//

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(@Model.TKota);
        alert(@Model.KKota);
        alert(@Model.BKota);
        alert(@Model.TKota + " " + @Model.KKota + " " + @Model.BKota);
    });
</script>
```

My problem is: 1st, 2nd and 3rd alerts showing right info but when I trying to take all info in one alert like 4th, I can get @Model.TKota, @Model.KKota but I can't get @Model.BKota value.

Consequently I can't use @Model.BKota in the following lines.

Comment: `alert("@Model.TKota + " " + @Model.KKota + " " + @Model.BKota);` looks like a syntax error,would occur due to the opening " not being closed. Try this: `alert(@Model.TKota + " " + @Model.KKota + " " + @Model.BKota);`

Comment: Sorry I edited my code.Its not about syntax error.Alert1 shows "100", alert2 shows "200", alert3 shows "300" but alert4 shows "100 200 " instead of "100 200 300".

Answer (score 3):

Your last alert is badly formatted, it should look like this

```
alert('@Model.TKota @Model.KKota @Model.BKota');
```

See the following fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yc8F4Q

Comment: Sorry I edited my code.Its not about syntax error.Alert1 shows "100", alert2 shows "200", alert3 shows "300" but alert4 shows "100 200 " instead of "100 200 300".

Comment: @BerkanToptaş in that case you don't have any value in `BKota` of the viewmodel, what's in the `bKota` variable? You could see in my fiddle that this is working.

Comment: I solved problem by casting int from double.bKota variable is type of double so after I cast it to int it worked.I think there were some issues about floating numbers..

Answer (score 0):

The clue is that you are not able to work with the variables after that statement, this usually means the parser has choked on something due to a syntax error.

`alert("@Model.TKota + " " + @Model.KKota + " " + @Model.BKota);` looks like a syntax error would occur here due to the opening " not being closed.

Try this:

```
alert('@Model.TKota @Model.KKota @Model.BKota');
```

Comment: That would not work if TKoda etc are anything else than numeric values

Comment: Sorry I edited my code.Its not about syntax error.Alert1 shows "100", alert2 shows "200", alert3 shows "300" but alert4 shows "100 200 " instead of "100 200 300".